# Removing a nested object using underscore.js _.omit

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, javascript-objects

I have a nested object e.g:

```
data.object = [Object],[Object],[Object],[Object]
```

I want to completely remove the 3rd Object, so `data.object[2]` should no longer exist and I should see:

```
data.object = [Object],[Object],[Object]
```

Using `delete` retains the 3rd object but as `undefined`:

```
data.object = [Object],[Object],undefined,[Object]
```

I understand that `_.omit` can be used in a similar way but my attempts do not work:

```
_.omit(data.object,data.object[2])
```

Comment: Instead of mutating the array in place, it's often better to create a new one without the element you want to remove, as in `data.object.filter((elt, i) => i !== 2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use underscore or any other third party library

```
data.object.splice(2, 1);
```

There is a standard JS function for that. It mutates the given array in-place, and removes the `1` element at the index `2`.

References:

- [Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)